# Alert returning "NaN" on global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm sure I'm just missing something super simple, but why isn't my click function grabbing the actual value from the askingPrice global variable? It just returns "NaN". It works perfectly fine if the askingPrice is inside the click function though.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var askingPrice = parseFloat( $("#mortcalc-ask").val().replace(/,/g,'') ); 
    var i = 0;

  $(".mortcalc-go").click(function(){
    var i = 1;
    alert(askingPrice + " is the cost");
  });

});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the value of `$("#mortcalc-ask").val().replace(/,/g,'')` ?

Comment: Because `$("#mortcalc-ask").val()` maybe return `NaN` on document load .. but while you used it inside the click .. for sure you input something to it before click so it returns the value

Comment: NaN stands for **Not a Number** so on the intial load, the variable gets set to whatever is there and will not change, assuming it is an empty value, this will be NaN. Whereas, when askingPrice is inside the click function it gets the value only on click, and I am guessing you are only clicking the button once askingPrice has a number inside it, so you will not get NaN.

Comment: The value of $("#mortcalc-ask") is linked to an <input> the client needs to fill in before hitting the button. It starts out as empty, but even then, on button click, after putting in a number into the input, it should spit out the number, right?

Comment: @Alec So what you're telling me is that once it gets the value of "NaN" on document load, that won't be overwritten on button click? Never came across that before :/

EDIT: Nvm... The answer down under cleared up my lapse in logic. Obviously, it won't change because it doesn't reset the variable inside the click function.. fml... Thanks guys!

Comment: @kenny Exactly! That's why when you retrieve the value of the input inside the on click event, it does not return NaN, so just assign askingPrice's value inside the click function, and wallah. Also, there is a shorthand method to `$(document).ready()`. It can be typed as `$(function() {} )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "global" variable (in the scope of the `ready` function) is being set at the time that the document is "ready", not at the time of the click.  If the user fills out some input field `#mortcalc-ask` and then clicks the button, the code to populate `askingPrice` isn't run again.  You will have to move that into the click handler.  (I've removed references to `i` since they don't seem to be relevant to your question.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var askingPrice;

  $(".mortcalc-go").click(function(){
    askingPrice = parseFloat( $("#mortcalc-ask").val().replace(/,/g,'') ); 
    alert(askingPrice + " is the cost");
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah... FML... I knew all this but there was a weird lapse in logic in my head till you wrote that all out... thanks!